# Usage of Pytest Fixture for screenshot(defined in conftest.py) and used with in a method under class structure

Tags: python, pytest, reportportal

Defined pytest fixture(names as rp_logger) in conftest.py file and trying to use in a method in different class as rp_logger.info(""). Getting an error that attribute info is not defined .

#### conftest file:

```
@pytest.fixture
def rp_logger(request):
    # Setting up a logging.
    logging.setLoggerClass(RPLogger)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Create handler for Report Portal.
    rp_handler = RPLogHandler(request.node.config.py_test_service)
    # Set INFO level for Report Portal handler.
    rp_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger
```

testsuite file:

```
@pytest.mark.single
@pytest.mark.events
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("rp_logger")
class MyTest(object):
    def test_verify_events_page(self, rp_logger):
        rp_logger.info("bbbb")
```

Error stack trace :

```
def run(self, result=None):
    orig_result = result
    if result is None:
        result = self.defaultTestResult()
        startTestRun = getattr(result, 'startTestRun', None)
        if startTestRun is not None:
            startTestRun()

    self._resultForDoCleanups = result
    result.startTest(self)

    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
    if (getattr(self.__class__, "__unittest_skip__", False) or
        getattr(testMethod, "__unittest_skip__", False)):
        # If the class or method was skipped.
        try:
            skip_why = (getattr(self.__class__, '__unittest_skip_why__', '')
                        or getattr(testMethod, '__unittest_skip_why__', ''))
            self._addSkip(result, skip_why)
        finally:
            result.stopTest(self)
        return
    try:
        success = False
        try:
            self.setUp()
        except SkipTest as e:
            self._addSkip(result, str(e))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise
        except:
            result.addError(self, sys.exc_info())
        else:
            try:
```

> ```
>               testMethod()
> ```
>
> E                   TypeError: test_verify_events_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Provide error traceback too.

Comment: updated the traceback.